# How to optimize information schema table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, optimization

When I checked slow running queries log, I found out that

`select count(*) into @discard from information_schema.PARTITIONS;`

This query is taking 6 seconds to execute (a bit higher for this execution). I am not really sure about usage of this query and would look advise on optimizing it.

Comment: You "found" it? The first question is... Who's running this query, and why?  Some graphical tools and monitoring systems run ridiculous queries in the background -- one of my favorites is `SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` which is either  ridiculously ill-concieved and pointless, or entirely brilliant, depending in what its purpose is (I lean toward the former) -- but information_schema queries can be bad for *overall* system performance because they can do expensive things under the hood.  I'd suggest that finding out why this is running is important.

Answer (score 1):

Information Schema is not like other databases:

> They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files
>   associated with them, and you cannot set triggers on them. Also, there
>   is no database directory with that name.

source - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html

and not a lot of ways for optimise queries over it
there are few recommendations (very standard for any queries)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema-optimization.html

recommendations is really standard and in Your case - with count(*) not help.

Answer (score 1):

Performance of `information_schema` will not improve until version 8.0.  At that point, the improvement will be quite dramatic.